# VBA Coding autofill destination variable

Tags: excel, vba

Please I would need your help

My case  : I have the column A to S filled, the number of lines is variable monthly but this is the same information (duplicate) and i put news lines into the column A to S (end of variable lines), and I would like also duplicate the new lines until empty cell from my column W (who is eveytime filled with other info). The issue with my code it's working until COPY. the end of the code for autofill destination who is variable is not working

Please see my code :

```
Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0).Select

 Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, 19)).Copy

 DernLigne = Range("W" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

  Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:A" & DernLigne)
```

what the issue is and the solution according to you ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to help but I dont clearly understand the issue. Can you give an example of how the data starts and how you want it to look at the end.

I dont understand the significance of the statement `Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, 19)).Copy` the copy buffer is never pasted anywhere? Have you missed a line where you intend to paste it somewhere?
In any case look at my suggestions, I think this could work, I commented out the 2 original lines I changed.

```
'Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0).Select
Dim LastRowNum As Long
LastRowNum = Cells.Rows.Count
Cells(LastRowNum, 1).End(xlUp).Select
    
    
'Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, 19)).Copy
    
Dim DernLigne As Integer
DernLigne = Range("W" & LastRowNum).End(xlUp).Row
    
'  Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:A" & DernLigne)
Range(Range("A2"), Range("A" & LastRowNum).End(xlUp)).AutoFill _
Destination:=Range("A2:A" & DernLigne)

' added lines
Range(Selection.Offset(0, 1), Selection.Offset(0, 18)).Copy
Range(Selection.Offset(1, 1), Selection.End(xlDown).Offset(0, 18)) _
      .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

[image: before/after screenshot]

Comment: Hi, it's working :) 

Thanks a lot for your help. This is perfect

Answer (score 0):

Hi thanks for your help,

it's not working :(

Please see a picture of the tab corresponding to my needs

the first 10 lines are variable each time (example line with ITSTAFF0001). I import at the end of the line a new line (example line with ITSTAFF0019 ; column A to S) and i would like to diplcated not all the line but information of the ITSTAFF0019 to 1254.056 (from colum A to S) unti empty cell from colum region

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHddl.png)
i hope it's helping you

Thanks

Comment: thanks for the screen shot see my amendments: You need to autofill and then copy the data (to make sure no autofill side effects)  - i added these lines at the end: 


```
' added lines
Range(Selection.Offset(0, 1), Selection.Offset(0, 18)).Copy
Range(Selection.Offset(1, 1), Selection.End(xlDown).Offset(0, 18)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```